# How to save(assign) the output from lapply into individual variables in R?

Tags: r, loops, save, lapply, assign

I have a very simple question but I've stocked in it! 
I have a list as an output :

as an example :

```
lapply(1:40, function(x){ (1+x)})
```

output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4
```

till

```
[[40]]
[1] 41
```

I wondered how can I assign each of the outputs of this list to a new variable by using a loop?
something like this

`a<- [[2]]; b <- [[3]]; ... az <- [[40]]` and so one.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: May I ask why you would want to do this?

Comment: You have more variables to assign(39) then letters(26).

Comment: yes, my function is different than this simple function. I have to use different cut-offs for some variables from 1-40 and it was much easier to use lapply and the function(x) to do it; but I don't know how to save the output individually! :)

Comment: @user3576287 when you say 'save' are you just trying to save each element to a separate file?  I'm just trying to figure out why you would want all these extra variables floating around in your workspace instead of working directly with the list elements.

Comment: Yes, I want to save each of them as an individual element in the global environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, it requires that your output of `lapply` is stored with the name `ll` but it can be easily modified I think.

```
ll <- lapply(1:40, function(x){ (1+x)})
nam <- "list_output_"
val <- c(1:length(ll))
for(i in 1:length(val)){
    assign(
        paste(nam, val, sep = "")[i], ll[[i]]
        ) }
```

The output will be `list_output_1` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I created a vector for the names and used a short loop. Maybe someone can vectorize it.

```
var_names <- c(letters, paste0(letters[1],letters[1:13]))
for(i in seq_along(var_names)) {
  assign(var_names[i], lapply(1:40, function(x){ (1+x)})[[i+1]])}

a
[1] 3
b
[1] 4
am
[1] 41
```