# Reading Excel file into R using readxl and httr/libxls error: Unable to open file

Tags: r, excel, url, httr, readxl

I'd like to read in sheet 1 of an Excel file from a website [Link](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/WEGWGS) using the url of the Excel file. I'm on windows 10, R 3.6.1.

I'm trying to use the code from [Read Excel file from a URL using the readxl package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368628/read-excel-file-from-a-url-using-the-readxl-package) and have also checked out [reading excel files into a single dataframe with readxl R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165717/reading-excel-files-into-a-single-dataframe-with-readxl-r).

```
url = 'https://dataverse.harvard.edu/file.xhtml?  persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/WEGWGS/I11K9Y&version=1.0'
GET(url, write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xls")))
df <- read_excel(tf, 1L)


# Error message
libxls error: Unable to open file
```

**I get the following error message:**

> libxls error: Unable to open file

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you scroll down that webpage (https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/WEGWGS), you will see that there is an explicit link for downloading the file directly (in the file meta-data box).

If you do the following, similar to your code above, you can retrieve the file correctly:

```
url = 'https://dataverse.harvard.edu/api/access/datafile/:persistentId?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/WEGWGS/I11K9Y'

library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(readxl)
httr::GET(url, write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")))
tf

df <- read_excel(tf, 1L)
```

Comment: Unless you can't access your temp path, like I also suffer from, `httr::GET(url, write_disk(tf <- "tmp.xlsx"))` helps there